# with-clause referenced two different from-clause elements in hSQL

Tags: java, hibernate

Getting the exception:

> With-clause referenced two different from-clause elements

When executing the query below with the following entities:

```
@Entity
public class A {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "A_ID")
    private Long aId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "A_ID")
    private B b;
}

@Entity
public class B {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="C_ID" , referencedColumnName="ID")
    private List<C> c;
}

@Entity
public class C {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="C_ID")
    private Long cId;

    @Column
    private String addType;
}
```

My HQL Query is:

```
SELECT * FROM A a 
INNER JOIN a.b b ON a.aId=b.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN b.c c ON b.id=c.cId AND c.addType='PermanentAddress' 
LEFT OUTER JOIN b.c d ON b.id=d.cId AND d.addType='ResidentialAddress'
LEFT OUTER JOIN b.c e ON b.id=e.cId AND e.addType='OfficeAddress'
WHERE a.id  =:id
```

The exception that I get is:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: with-clause referenced two different from-clause elements 
>         at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:91)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:109)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:284)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:206)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:126)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:88)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:167)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1800)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:328)
>   ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
>         ... 187 common frames omitted

Answer (score 19):

You don't need the ON clauses in your query. Hibernate does automatically link the models.

Comment: Helped at similar case, just replaced `on` to `where`. Thanks.

Comment: @attofi all on with "where" ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the ON clauses and conditions in your query, since you only use the FK, which is implicit anyway.

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM A a
INNER JOIN a.b b
LEFT OUTER JOIN b.c c WITH c.addType='PermanentAddress' 
LEFT OUTER JOIN b.c d WITH d.addType='ResidentialAddress'
LEFT OUTER JOIN b.c e WITH e.addType='OfficeAddress'
WHERE a.id  =:id
```